# How can I use shelf_web_socket to listen for http and ws requests on the same port

Tags: dart, dart-io, dart-http, dart-shelf

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shelf_web_socket shows this example

```dart
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart' as shelf_io;
import 'package:shelf_web_socket/shelf_web_socket.dart';

void main() {
  var handler = webSocketHandler((webSocket) {
    webSocket.listen((message) {
      webSocket.add("echo $message");
    });
  });

  shelf_io.serve(handler, 'localhost', 8080).then((server) {
    print('Serving at ws://${server.address.host}:${server.port}');
  });
}
```

I would like to know how to combine this with my HTTP server initialization

```dart
import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart' as shelf;
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart' as sIo;
import 'package:shelf_auth/shelf_auth.dart' as sAuth;
import 'package:shelf_auth/src/authentication.dart' as sAuth2;
import 'package:option/option.dart';
import 'package:shelf_web_socket/shelf_web_socket.dart' as sWs;

...

var authMiddleware = sAuth.authenticate(
    [new MyAuthenticator()],
    sessionHandler: new sAuth.JwtSessionHandler('bla', 'blub', new UserLookup()),
    allowHttp: true,
    allowAnonymousAccess: false);

var handler = const shelf.Pipeline()
    .addMiddleware(shelf.logRequests())
    .addMiddleware(authMiddleware)
    .addHandler(_handleHttpRequest);

// var wsHandler = sWs.webSocketHandler(_handleWebSocketConnect);

sIo.serve(handler, '0.0.0.0', servePort).then((server) {
  _log.finest('Serving at http://${server.address.host}:${server.port}');
});
```

What needs to be done so that `wsHandler` gets called for WebSocket connects and `handler` keeps handling HTTP requests (if possible on the same port) and if possible uses the configured authentication and session management.

I tried it on a different port but with the authentication/session middleware (no idea if this is supposed to be used together)

```dart
   var authMiddleware = sAuth.authenticate(
        [new MyAuthenticator()],
        sessionHandler: new sAuth.JwtSessionHandler('bla', 'blub', new UserLookup()),
        allowHttp: true,
        allowAnonymousAccess: false);

    var handler = const shelf.Pipeline()
        .addMiddleware(shelf.logRequests())
        .addMiddleware(authMiddleware)
        .addHandler(_handleHttpRequest);

    sIo.serve(handler, '0.0.0.0', servePort).then((server) {
      _log.finest('Serving at http://${server.address.host}:${server.port}');
    });


    var wsHandler = const shelf.Pipeline()
      .addMiddleware(shelf.logRequests())
      .addMiddleware(authMiddleware)
      .addHandler(sWs.webSocketHandler(_handleWebSocketConnect));

    sIo.serve(wsHandler, '0.0.0.0', servePort + 1).then((server) {
      _log.finest('Serving at ws://${server.address.host}:${server.port}');
    });
```

and got

```dart
Illegal argument(s): webSocketHandler may only be used with a server that supports request hijacking.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the moment your root handler is the http handler. You'll need to set up a handler that conditionally sends requests to the ws handler or another handler for your http requests. Eg

/ws -> your ws handler

/rest -> your other handler

The easiest way to do that is to use a router like shelf_route.

However someone recently tried this and hit a [bug in shelf that stopped this working](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21043). Which as you noted below is fixed but not merged.

Once the issue is fixed you should be able to do

```dart
import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart' as shelf;
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart' as io;
import 'package:shelf_route/shelf_route.dart' as route;
import 'package:shelf_web_socket/shelf_web_socket.dart' as sWs;
import 'package:shelf_auth/shelf_auth.dart' as sAuth;
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:option/option.dart';
import 'package:shelf_exception_response/exception_response.dart';

void main(List<String> arguments) {

  var authMiddleware = sAuth.authenticate(
        [new MyAuthenticator()],
        sessionHandler: new sAuth.JwtSessionHandler('bla', 'blub', new UserLookup()),
        allowHttp: true,
        allowAnonymousAccess: false);


  var router = (route.router()
      ..get('/rest', _handleHttpRequest)
      ..get('/ws', sWs.webSocketHandler(_handleWebSocketConnect)));

  var handler = const shelf.Pipeline()
      .addMiddleware(exceptionResponse())
      .addMiddleware(shelf.logRequests())
      .addMiddleware(authMiddleware)
      .addHandler(router.handler);

  route.printRoutes(router);

  io.serve(handler, '127.0.0.1', 8080).then((server) {
    print('Serving at http://${server.address.host}:${server.port}');
  });
}
```

Until the issue is fixed you can replace the router.handler with

```dart
var hackyRouterHandler = (shelf.Request request) {
  var path = request.url.path;
  if (path.startsWith('/rest')) {
    return _handleHttpRequest(request);
  }
  else if (path.startsWith('/ws')) {
    return sWs.webSocketHandler(_handleWebSocketConnect)(request);
  }
  else {
    throw new NotFoundException();
  }
};
```

Comment: In the meantime you can look at https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/m/#!searchin/misc/shelf/misc/PrkSD9iVISs
It has such an example. Unfortunately it looks like the shelf issue is not fixed yet. It's a pity it's not on gh as it's such a small change

Comment: This is ready for code review since 3 days https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=21043

Comment: If only we could approve, merge and publish it ;-)

Comment: Great! I wanted to try shelf for quite a while but couldn't find the time. I started using it because of the session handler in your `shelf_auth` package.

Comment: Btw, I have the fix in my Git repository here till a new version is published: https://github.com/Fox32/shelf